# Creating Hexagons in css / html

Tags: css, html

Im trying to make a couple of hexagons in css /html to resemble something like this:

http://www.asta-uk.com/sites/all/themes/asta/logo.png

now i have made one hexagon, and tried to copy it two other times but the top part doesn't seem to show on the second two.

any ideas why?

PS use IE, reason being it will only ever be used in an IE environment.

```
   <html>
     <HEAD>

       <STYLE>


.top 
{
    height:0;
    width:50;
    display: block;
    border:15px solid red;
    border-top-color:transparent;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:red;
    border-left-color:transparent;
}

.middle 
{
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
}

.bottom 
{
    height:0;
    width:50;
    display: block;
    border:15px solid red;
    border-top-color:red;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    border-left-color:transparent;
}

<!-- Second Hex-->

.top2 
{
    height:0;
    width:50;
    display: block;
    border: 15px solid black;
    border-top-color:transparent;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:black;
    border-left-color:transparent;
}

.middle2 
{
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
}

.bottom2 
{
    height:0;
    width:50;
    display: block;
    border:15px solid black;
    border-top-color:black;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    border-left-color:transparent;
}

<!--hex 3-->

.top3 
{
    height:0;
    width:50;
    display: block;
    border:15px solid green;
    border-top-color:transparent;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:green;
    border-left-color:transparent;
}

.middle3 
{
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
}
.bottom3 
{
    height:0;
    width:50;
    display: block;
    border:15px solid green;
    border-top-color:green;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    border-left-color:transparent;
}




</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

 <div class="hexagon"style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 2px;">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="middle"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>

</div>
<!-- GREEN-->
 <div class="hexagon3" style="position: absolute; top: 48px; left: 55px;">
    <span class="top3"></span>
    <span class="middle3"></span>
    <span class="bottom3"></span>

</div>
<!-- black-->
 <div class="hexagon2" style="position: absolute; top: 120px; left: 40px;">
    <span class="top2"></span>
    <span class="middle2"></span>
    <span class="bottom2"></span>

</div>



</BODY

</html>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing this? HTML+CSS isn't meant for the creation of original artwork, that task is better suited to SVG.

Comment: it is for a logo that will be used in emails, the reason i can't use an image is because some mail client will block images

Comment: If it's for emails then I don't recommend it anyway. Outlook (since 2007) uses Word's HTML rendering engine which is *awful*. I guarantee these hexagons won't render. The alternative is to include the logo image as an attachment on every email. That way mail clients won't block the images.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. This approach is *just not going to work*. Even if it does work, it won't work consistently between different email clients. Use an image.

Comment: I'll say it to the guys upstairs, i'm just following instructions at the moment. thanks anyway guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your comment from the css

like `<!-- Second Hex-->` and `<!--hex 3-->`
they are buggy.

These comments are meant to be in `HTML` only not for `css`

for css use this syntax --> `/* A comment */`

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in `width:50;` Add `px` so it should be `width:50px;` for `.top, .top2, .top3`

Comment: i noticed that after i posted it but it didn't make a difference :( the top of the second 2 hexagons still dont show.