# How can I rotate these hexagons?

Tags: html, css

> Hi, I am just wondering could anyone help me out with this problem, I have to rotate these three hexagons slightly. Around 15 degrees or so. It has to work in internet explorer only. I have been banging my head against this all day and it is quite frustrating. 
>   Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>

 <style type="text/css">

    .top 
                {
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        display: block;
        border:50px solid #606060;
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:#606060;
        border-left-color:transparent;
                                //transform: rotate(30deg);
    }

    .middle 
                {
        height: 50px;
        background: #606060;
        width: 100px;
        display: block;
                                //transform: rotate(30deg);
    }

    .bottom
                {
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        display: block;
        border:50px solid #606060;
        border-top-color:#606060;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:transparent;
        border-left-color:transparent;
                                // transform: rotate(30deg);

    }

    .top2 
                {
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        display: block;
        border:50px solid red;
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:red;
        border-left-color:transparent;
                                //transform: rotate(30deg);
    }

    .middle2 
                {
        height: 50px;
        background: red;
        width: 100px;
        display: block;
                                //transform: rotate(30deg);
    }

    .bottom2 
                {
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        display: block;
        border:50px solid red;
        border-top-color:red;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:transparent;
        border-left-color:transparent;
                                // transform: rotate(30deg);

    }

                .top3 
                {
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        display: block;
        border:50px solid #C0C0C0;
        border-top-color:transparent;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:#C0C0C0;
        border-left-color:transparent;
                                //transform: rotate(30deg);
    }

    .middle3 
                {
        height: 50px;
        background: #C0C0C0;
        width: 100px;
        display: block;
                                //transform: rotate(30deg);
    }

    .bottom3
                {
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        display: block;
        border:50px solid #C0C0C0;
        border-top-color:#C0C0C0;
        border-right-color:transparent;
        border-bottom-color:transparent;
        border-left-color:transparent;
                                // transform: rotate(30deg);

    }



 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="hexagon"style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 10px;">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="middle"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>

</div>
<!-- GREEN -->
 <div class="hexagon3" style="position: absolute; top: 110px; left: 65px;">
    <span class="top3"></span>
    <span class="middle3"></span>
    <span class="bottom3"></span>

</div>
<!-- black-->
 <div class="hexagon2" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 120px;">
                <span class="top2"></span>
    <span class="middle2"></span>
    <span class="bottom2"></span>

</div>



</BODY

</html>
```

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but this look suspiciously similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450967/creating-hexagons-in-css-html

Comment: What's the effect you're seeing. That no rotation takes place if you uncomment the transform? or that it's not looking how you want it to?

Comment: It seems one of the lads already posted about it. Balls. Thanks.

Comment: There is no rotation whatsoever no matter what. @OnResolve

Comment: @user1521288 - it sounds like you found your answer but in case not: IE doesn't support the `transform` rule in css.  Depending on your version of IE, you can use `-m-transform` or ggonzalez's answer provides a workaround that I believe works with older versions.

Comment: I haven't found it yet no. I have tried the -m-transform since and it just makes the top half of one hexagon disappear out of the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS for transforms in explorer :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */
M11=0.9659258262890683, M12=-0.25881904510252074, M21=0.25881904510252074, M22=0.9659258262890683, sizingMethod='auto expand');
zoom: 1;
```

Take a look in this page http://css3please.com/